# How to resolve conflicts in symbol packages?

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I want to use symbols from `wasysym` and `marvosym` packages:

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{marvosym}
```

but it gives an errors as both packages have the command of `\CheckedBox`. I do not want to use this command, but since both packages have it, it makes confusion for latex. How can I ignore one command to have both packages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you load the packages in the other order, then everything works fine.

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
```

If you want to keep them in the order you currently have, then the following works

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\let\CheckedBox\relax
\usepackage{marvosym}
```

Comment: In the last version of `marvosym.sty`, the command `\CheckedBox` is not defined any more (there's always been the alias `\Checkedbox`).

Comment: @cmhughes I like your second solution, as conflicts may happen with other packages too. For example, I have conflict of `/Cross` for `marvosym` and `bbding`.

Answer (score 9):

As **cmhughes** indicates, sometimes loading the packages in reverse order solves the problem. However, if reversing the order still produces clashes, or if, for some reason, reversing the order is not an option, there's a nice procedure to prevent symbol names clashes when two packages define the same symbol(s): load the first package, rename the conflicting symbols, and then load the second package. The `\savesymbol` command from the `savesym` package can be used to this; `\savesymbol{XXX}` renames a symbol from `\XXX` to `\origXXX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\savesymbol{CheckedBox}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\CheckedBox\qquad\origCheckedBox

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very interesting solution. It will be a tricky approach, useful for many cases we may face; particularly when we do not want to miss a conflicted symbol.