# suppress single macro from style file

Tags: macros, preamble

I have a master style file of macros, which I use for all of my documents. Is there something I can add to the preamble of a particular file so that it ignores some specific macro from my style file?

For example. My style file includes my custom shortcut `\foo`. Now I am writing a specific document, and I want to use some unusual symbol that is part of some random package I never use. So I add this package to the preamble of this document, to get the command for the unusual symbol. But this package happens to use the command `\foo` for some other thing I don't care about, and so now I get the `\foo already defined` error when I try to compile. I would like to add something to the preamble of this document so that it ignores `\foo` in my style file. Is this possible?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\foo}{}` or for a symbol `savesymbol` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's a symbol, which I assume is why `\renewcommand{\foo}{}` doesn't work. I am not familiar with the `savesymbol` package, and I couldn't figure out how to implement it. However, when searching for info on `savesymbol`, I found [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52554/how-to-resolve-conflicts-in-symbol-packages), which provides an answer. In particular, I add `\let\foo\relax` to the preamble between `\usepackage{mymacros}` and `\usepackage{randompacakge}`. Should I delete the question?

Comment: `\let\foo\relax` can work but you won't be able to access the original definition then

Comment: I made an error as well: The name is `savesym`, not `savesymbol`, but the command is called that way, sorry about!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the `savesym` way of getting rid of this problem:

`\savesymbol{foo}` should work, after that say `\origfoo` to access the old version.

The classical conflict appears for example with `bbding` and `marvosym` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{savesym}

\usepackage{bbding}
\savesymbol{Cross}

\usepackage{marvosym}


\begin{document}

Original version: \origCross

Redefined version: \Cross


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spelling out how to use the `savesym` package.

Comment: @Gabe: You're welcome! Happy TeXing!