# How to solve: "! LaTeX Error: Command \Square already defined."

Tags: macros, errors, lyx, amsmath, bbding

I'm using LyX (2.2.3), I need to use `bbding`:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\let\Square\relax
\usepackage{bbding}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\L{$\leadsto$}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

When I remove the `bbding` there are no errors, but I need it...

Comment: The problem is that both `wasysym` and `bbding` define the `\Square` command. A workaround for a similar problem is described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52554/how-to-resolve-conflicts-in-symbol-packages and seems to work in your case, too (changing the include order of both packages or using the `\let\Square\relax` version).

Comment: @epR8GaYuh - _"changing the include order of both packages"_ - how to do that?

Comment: The solution of: `\let\Square\relax` doesn't work :-(

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{wasysym}` in the upper part of your preamble and add it after `\usepackage{bbding}` again. Otherwise, the `\let\Square\relax` needs to be placed between `\usepackage{wasysym}` and `\usepackage{bbding}` - you probably tried to do this after the `bbding` include.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh - I tried to put it **before** the bbding and it doesn't work... How do I remove the `\usepackage{wasysym}`? I'm using LyX... Thank you!

Comment: Hm, that might be a bit tricky, I don't think you have any direct influence over that part of the preamble. LyX automatically adds `\usepackage{wasysym}` when  you use a symbol from that package in the document.  What exactly doesn't work when you add `\let\Square\relax` before `\usepackage{bbding}`?

Comment: Wired, but now it's works fine!! Thank you!!

Comment: There may have been a second \usepackage{wasysim} in the aux file and it took two runs to get rid of it.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate as the `\let` trick (and probably also the `\savesymbol` method) worked fine after all. Let me know if you disagree with this, I can reopen.